# What does 'a bear' mean here as a noun?

Tags: meaning

What does 'a bear' mean here as a noun?

> “I say, ‘No, it’s a serious degree, a chemistry degree first and
>   foremost. It’s hard work. Organic chemistry is **a bear**,” the 27 year
>   old told the Associated Press.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A bear" is a slang expression (at least in the US; not sure about other countries) for something that is very bad, scary, horrible, a nightmare, a big problem, difficult, or impossible, etc. I think it is a euphemism for "a bitch", because it starts with the same sound, but you can use "bear" in situations where "bitch" might not be acceptable.

Comment: Similar to "a beast".